# Rails API: Cannot whitelist JSON field attribute

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building a rails API with a model containing an attribute `data` of JSON type. (PSQL)

But when I try to post something like this

```
{ model: { name: 'Hello', data: { a: 1, b: 2 } } }
```

Rails thinks `a` and `b` are the attributes of a nested `data` association... It considers then they are unpermitted params.
The thing is, `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` is the value of my field `data`.

How to provide JSON value to an attribute ?

#### Edit:

The error displayed is:

```
Unpermitted parameters: name, provider, confidence, location_type, formatted_address, place_id, types, locality, ...
```

The value of the data attribute is `{ name: 'Name', provider: 'Provider', ... }`

Like I said Rails thinks they are the attributes of a nested `data` association.

Log:
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/yvTDL9AJ)

Comment: can you paste the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Done, replace `a` and `b` with `name`, `provider` etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the keys are unknown in advance this could be a workaround:

```
def model_params
   data_keys = params[:model].try(:fetch, :data, {}).keys
   params.require(:model).permit(data: data_keys)
end
```

Credit goes to aliibrahim, read the discussion https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454 (P.S seems like strong parameters will support this use case in Rails 5.1)

Comment: What about unknown metadata ? if I don't know key:value pairs I will send in data: {}

Comment: @TerryRaimondo Edited the answer to support unknown keys

Comment: Oh nice ! Will try in a few hours

Answer (score 0):

When you post something, you have to make sure that your json have the same parameters that your controller.

Example rails api:

```
def example
 @model = Model.new(params)
 @model.save
 render(json: model.to_json, status: :ok)
end

def params
 params.permit(:name, :provider, {:data => [:a, :b]})
end
```

Example front-end json for post:

```
var body = {
 name: 'myName',
 provider: 'provider',
 data: {
  a: 'something',
  b: 'otherthing',
 }
};
```

For some reason rails doesnt recognize a nested json, so you need to write into **params.permit** that **data** will be a json with that syntax, if where a array, the **[]** should be empty.

Comment: What about unknown metadata ? if I don't know key:value pairs I will send in data: {}

Comment: You can  send a hash and rails can iterate over the logic if I remember well is the same that empty array.

Answer (score 0):

If using Rails v7

```
    def model_params
      params.require(:model).permit(:name, data: {})
    end
```

[Reference](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e86524c0c5a26ceec92895c830d1355ae47a7034)